# Will Preprocessor Definitions in Precompiled Headers cause recompilation

Tags: c++, precompiled-headers

Will putting Preprocessor Definitions in Precompiled Headers cause the invalidation of the precompiled cache? For example:

```cpp
#ifdef MY_DEF
void some_func() {
    // do one thing
}
#else
void some_func() {
    // do another thing
}
#endif
```

```sh
g++ -D MY_DEF ...
```

vs

```sh
g++ ...
```

Comment: What do you mean? `gcc` never rebuilds precompiled headers automatically. You have to do it manually or use a tool such as `make`.

Comment: I just brought that as an example. Truethfully, I am using Visual Studio, so it's automated. I should probably look into how gcc handles precopiled headers